# Script activity not pausing and deleting the TS

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, ssjs, automationstudio, wsproxy

I am trying to Pause and Delete the Triggered sends present in out account which were created/used before 3 years. Below code works fine in a CloudPage but does not perform any action when using it in Script activity in Automation.
Is this not supported in Script activity?

```
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core","1.1.5");
try{

var myDE = DataExtension.Init("DEExternalKey");
var data = myDE.Rows.Retrieve();
  
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var name = data[i].Name;
    var customerKey = data[i].CustomerKey;
    var tsd = TriggeredSend.Init(customerKey);
    var pause = tsd.Pause();
    
    var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
    var del = prox.deleteItem("TriggeredSendDefinition", { "CustomerKey":customerKey });
    
var logDE = DataExtension.Init("LogDE");
    logDE.Rows.Add({"PauseLog":pause, "DeleteLog":del, "TSName":name, "ExternalKey":customerKey});
    
  }

 }
 catch (err) {
  Write("Error Message: " + Stringify(err.message) + Stringify(err.description));
 }
</script>
```

Comment: I used impersonation using WSProxy still I get the error when pausing and deleting the TS.

Comment: I even used only pause code to pause the TS as pausing the TS may need some time and deletion may fail, but pause code also logs error in LogDE

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: Hi @SwatiMishra There is no specific error. The details captured in LogDE is "Error" with no description. When checked with SF Support, they are also not able to provide any details for this error.

Comment: I added a try catch block around the delete code line, it seems working for me. I also changed Platform.Load("core", "1"); - Should not make much difference

Comment: There is no error in the SSJS script, the issue is that this script does not delete the TS when used in Script activity but works when used in CloudPage. I want to schedule the deletion and needs that to work in Script activity

Comment: I tried it and it's working for me

Comment: It worked for me when the Triggered send did not send any emails. When I used it for other TS where emails were triggered, they just don't delete. I also used AMPScript in code snippet and called this code snippet block in script activity using below code, but no success

<script runat="server">
  Platform.Load("Core","1.1.1");
  var content = Platform.Function.ContentBlockByKey("ExternalKeyxxxx");
  Platform.Response.Write(Platform.Function.TreatAsContent(content));
</script>